# Como evitar uma vulnerabilidade XSS num FORM HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Como evitar ter vulnerabilidades XSS num formulário, usando a tag `<form> </form>`, em HTML? Existe alguma boa prática em construção de código HTML para evitá-la?

Answer (score 2):

XSS não tem a ver com a tag form em particular. Fundamentalmente, o problema é quando você inclui algum texto controlável pelo usuário em algum lugar que será interpretado como HTML ao invés de texto. A solução para isso é na hora de produzir o HTML você escapar todos os caracteres especiais de dados que são texto mas estão sendo inseridos no seu documento (tanto dentro de uma tag como em atributos). Além disso você tem que tomar cuidado para não passar dados do usuário pra tags script ou pra função eval.

Essa página tem uma descrição bastante compreensiva sobre XSS e como evitar o problema: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet